# Can all $O(n)$ problems be solved without nested loops?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics

There are examples of algorithm implementations that contain nested loops but are of complexity O(n), and some of them have corresponding implementations that contain no nested loops. So here comes a question, can all such implementations be simplified or converted to an implementation with only top layer loops? Namely, can all problems that have an $O(n)$ algorithm be solved with an algorithm without nested loops?

Comment: What do "nested loops" mean? What about the [linear time selection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians), which is recursive?

Comment: For any algorithm, you can find another algorithm with a single loop that computes the same thing. The idea is that if you keep an integer of "where you are in the original program", and in the unique loop, you have a big case analysis on this integer. This allows to simulate jumps (by changing the integer) and therefore loops.

Comment: It might be a surprise to you, but "nested loop" is not a well-defined concept although it looks like very clear intuitively. For example, Turing machine is defined without any reference to a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write an interpreter for any reasonable instruction set usin a single loop with a very, very long if/ else if / else if... statement. That should cover about all solvable problems. You can calculate the Ackerman function with one loop without recursion (not in the lifetime of the universe for n >= 4, but in principle).

Comment: So not only $O(n)$ algorithms, but all algorithms can be implemented with one loop?

Comment: All that can be implemented on any reasonable machine.